# Get all contacts at least one phone number in ngCordova Contacts plugin

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using the ngcordova [contacts plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/contacts/) to retrieve the contacts in an app. I'd like to know if it is possible to get only the contacts that have at least one phone Number.

I have use the following code , It returns the my google contacts which contains email but not phone numbers. But I want only available phone number not emails.
Is this possible ? or any other option available to get this result.

```
$scope.getContactList = function() {
         $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Loading...'
        });
        var options = {};
        options.multiple = true;
        options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
        options.fields = ['name.formatted', 'phoneNumbers'];
        $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(function(result) {
            $scope.contacts = result;
            $ionicLoading.hide();

        }, function(error) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + error);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution without using  any external js , code shown as follows :

```
$scope.getContactList = function() {
      $scope.contacts = [];
             $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'Loading...'
            });
            var options = {};
            options.multiple = true;
            $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(function(result) {
                 for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var contact = result[i];
                     if(contact.phoneNumbers != null)
                       $scope.contacts.push(contact);
                  }
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: how can I use $cordovaContacts.find in the ui side to display auto complete list... means i want to make an app where when i type a name or number inside input automatically it should display relevant number or name...please help me, i need to fix this

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using http://underscorejs.org/ in order to filter the contacts result. Something like this should suit your needs:

```
$scope.getContactList = function() {
     $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Loading...'
    });
    var options = {};
    options.multiple = true;
    options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
    options.fields = ['name.formatted', 'phoneNumbers'];
    $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(function(result) {
        $scope.contacts = result;

        var contactsWithAtLeastOnePhoneNumber = _.filter(result, function(contact){
            return contact.phoneNumbers.length > 0
        });

        //
        // Contacts with at least one phone number...
        console.log(contactsWithAtLeastOnePhoneNumber);

        $ionicLoading.hide();

    }, function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    });
}
```

Because the `phoneNumbers` array can be returned and be blank, this quick method ensures that at least one entry is present.

Comment: I am not getting result ,Please tell me result in which variable ?

Comment: I have test on android device

Comment: what would be it's html code? `ng-repeat`. I'm using `<ion-item ng-repeat="contact in phoneContacts | filter: searchContacts"> {{ contact.name.formatted }} </ion-item>` What error am I making?